# How to update a jQuery variable before retrieving it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a very simple jQuery script for a responsive site that allows the topnav to become "sticky" when scrolling past its location. ([You can see it working here.](http://dannymcgeesandbox.nationbuilder.com)) It also adds/removes the height of the stickynav to/from the top-margin of the body and another element to remove the sudden jump when the menu becomes fixed. This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var theLoc = $('nav#menu').position().top;
  var navHeight = $('nav#menu').height();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if(theLoc >= $(window).scrollTop()) {
      if($('nav#menu').hasClass('fixed')) {
        $('nav#menu').removeClass('fixed');
        $('body').css('margin-top', '0');
        $('nav#hidden-menu').css('margin-top', '0');
      }
    } else { 
      if(!$('nav#menu').hasClass('fixed')) {
        $('nav#menu').addClass('fixed');
        $('body').css('margin-top', navHeight);
        $('nav#hidden-menu').css('margin-top', -navHeight);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that the height of the stickynav changes depending on the size of the window. (It's completely absent at less than 768px wide, small from 768 - 1280, and larger at 1280 and wider.) However, the navHeight variable retains the same value as when the page first loaded—so if you load the page, resize the window so that the nav height changes, and then scroll down past the nav, the script no longer works as intended.

How would I write this in such a way that the navHeight variable updates when the window is resized? I tried putting the var declaration directly before it's called for in the script, hoping that it would update the value whenever it's called, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a window resize handler that updates the value of `navHeight`.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theLoc = $('nav#menu').position().top;
    var navHeight = $('nav#menu').height();

    ...

    $(window).resize(function() {
        navHeight = $('nav#menu').height();
    });
});
```